# How to Create Stored Procedure using DbContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create below stored procedure using `DbContext`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upGetTestID 
     @WOID NVARCHAR(60), 
     @SampleID NVARCHAR(60),
     @Analyte NVARCHAR(60)
AS
    SELECT TestID
    FROM tblWOSampleTest
    JOIN tblTest ON tblTest.TestID = tblWOSampleTest.TestID 
    WHERE @WOID = tblWOSampleTest.WOID 
      AND @SampleID = tblWOSampleTest.SampleID 
      AND @Analyte = tblTest.Analyte
GO
```

I want to create above stored procedure by extending `DbContext` class using

```
System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder
```

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: I think you want to create a stored procedure then connect it by entity framework through the class DbContext , isn't it?

Comment: Yes @MuhammadAshikuzzaman

Comment: Are you working in asp .net mvc or in console?

Answer (score 1):

Put the parameters in first bracket. Create the stored procedure, then connect to database by Entity Framework. When you will want to create context file from database then you will see option with tables, view and stored procedure. Also you will see this stored procedure there. And then follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [upGetTestID]
    (@WOID nvarchar(60),
     @SampleID nvarchar(60),
     @Analyte nvarchar(60)) 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT TestID  
    FROM tblWOSampleTest
    JOIN tblTest ON tblTest.TestID = tblWOSampleTest.TestID  
    WHERE @WOID = tblWOSampleTest.WOID 
          AND tblWOSampleTest.SampleID = @SampleID 
          AND tblTest.Analyte = @Analyte 
END
```

Comment: Also: you need to get rid of that exact `;` at the end of the `JOIN` line to make it proper, valid T-SQL syntax....